# How do I stop controller execution after using render? (Using Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have this method:

```
 def index
  urls = parse_urls(params[:urls])

  responses = Parallel.map (urls) do |url|
    begin
     get url
    rescue  RestClient::Exception
      case params[:errors]
      when 'fail_any'
      render :json => fail_any
      when 'replace'
      replace
      else
      render :json => { :error => 'UNKNOWN_ERROR_TYPE'},status: 400
      end
       {:result=>'failed'}
    end
  end
```

But I want to stop the controller execution after rendering.
I tried to add break after the render but I get an error message

```
Parallel::DeadWorker

Marshal.load(read)
  rescue EOFError
    raise DeadWorker
  end
  raise result.exception if ExceptionWrapper === result
  result
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The problem solved by using threads instead of processes (the default option)

```
  responses = Parallel.map(urls, :in_threads => 3) do |url|
```

Answer (score 10):

Use: `return`:

```
return render :json => fail_any
```

or, use `return` after the `render :json ...` line like:

```
render :json => fail_any
return
```

#### Update:

```
render :text => "No Data" and return if some_condition
```

or, simply `render and return` if you are sure you want to stop the controller execution at this point:

```
render :text => "No Data" and return
```

**This ensures that execution stops after encountering the statement and no flow happens anymore in the action code as it sees a return.**

This article on [Render and Return](http://www.scholarsandarticles.com/render-and-return/) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, but that was not the problem.
The problem solved by using threads instead of processes (the default option)
anyway, thank you!
Yoel